# Integral to be computed

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I am interested in computing 
$$J(a,b):=\int_{\mathcal{I}(a,b)}\frac{dx \ dy\  dz}{|ax^3+ay^2+bz^3|^{2/3}},
$$
where $a,b$ are natural numbers and 
$$\mathcal{I}(a,b):=(0,1]^3\cap\{x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}:|ax^3+ay^2+bz^3|\leq b\}.
$$

In case a closed formula cannot be found, I would be equally content with
an upper bound of the correct order of magnitude as $a,b \to +\infty.$

Comment: Is there context to this integral? Why the third powers for $x$ and $z$ and second power for $y$?

Comment: Also there are some things you could do. 

1) You can drop the absolute values since you are dealing with natural numbers $a$ and $b$ and positive variables $x,y,z$.

2)If you divide out by $a$ and let $c = b/a$ you get an integrand involving $1/(x^3+y^2+cz^3)^{2/3}$. The region of integration involves the intersection of the region where $(x^3+y^2+c z^3) \leq c$. This allows you to bound the region by a box $(0,1]^3 \cap ((0,c^{1/3}]\times (0,c^{1/2}]\times(0,1])$.